# Register a Javascript with a different mime type with Plone

Tags: plone, mathjax, plone-4.x

I have a Plone product for integration of MathJax; because the usual way of reading everything from the cdn network doesn't work well for me, I forked https://github.com/collective/collective.mathjax to use the packaged MathJax.  (I also don't like to have a script reference with a query string on every page, while most of them not even contain formulas).

However, according to [MathJax documentation: Using in-line configuration options](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#inline-config), I should better have a configuration script with a `text/x-mathjax-config` mime type. From the looking at it, adjusting the mime type seems not to be possible in the Javascript registry.

So, how can I register a resource with a customized mime type?  Or do I need to build the script element manually?

Comment: Well, that doesn't look like it's too much code, have you considered registering a viewlet for HtmlHead and just putting that in a template? You can't merge the config with other JS while maintaining the separate mime-type anyway.

Comment: Well, the `MathJax.js` can't be merged either (not even "cached", since it would loose its virtual directory).  If I understand you correctly, the answer is: I can't, not easily at least.  For my integration product, I found another solution, which works for MathJax 2.3+: I use a "configuration object", which can be ordinary Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can store MathJax configuration blocks in regular JavaScript elements.

This is documented on [the docs page you linked to](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#inline-config) (just a little further down).

To quote:

> Starting with MathJax version 2.3, it is possible to set window.MathJax to a configuration object in any Javascript code before MathJax’s startup. MathJax will then use that object for its initial configuration. For instance the previous example becomes:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.MathJax = {
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML">
```

You can put this kind of configuration into a separate file as well; just make sure you load the configuration before MathJax. If you want to load it via the query string on `MathJax.js`, then make sure to follow http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#using-a-local-configuration-file-with-the-cdn

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my comment from April 25th, I use a _configuration object_ now; and below I include the `MathJax.js` script _without_ query string, because it won't be cached otherwise.  This is currently good enough for me, but I'm not sure whether this solution is equally powerful like the `text/x-mathjax-config` solution.

Comment: They are equivalent ways of configuring MathJax. (With respect to caching, you mean your setup, right? In general, URLs with query strings can be cached just the same)

Comment: According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching?hl=sv) (the recommendations at the bottom), query strings for static resources look like bad practice to me.

Comment: That's what I meant with "your system" (bad choice of words on my part though, sorry). If a system won't cache urls with query strings the yes, don't use them. But lots of services do (eg CDN providers).

Comment: IMO, it's exactly the other way round: If your content is cacheable by nature, find a way to provide it without a query string.  Furthermore, there are a plethora of user's browsers involved; I won't rely on every single one of them to behave the same regarding this (unless given a _very good_ source which told me this would be ok).